# Kotlin compiler error: Type mismatch. Required: CapturedType(out A) Found: A

Tags: kotlin, generics, compiler-errors

Can you explain me why I am getting this error?

```
interface A

open class B<T>

class Foo: A

class Item<T : A>(
    val clazz: Class<out A>,
    val b: B<out A>
)

val items = mutableListOf<Item<out A>>(
    Item(
        Foo::class.java,
        B<Foo>()
    )
)

fun <T : Any?> doSomething(
    type: Class<T>?,
    param: B<T>
) {
    // Nothing
}

fun main() {
    doSomething(items[0].clazz, items[0].b) // compiler error on 2nd argument
    // Type mismatch.
    // Required: CapturedType(out A)
    // Found: A
}
```

Second param in `doSomething` of type `B<T>`, so I can't understand why I am not able to pass object of type `B<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Second param in `doSomething` of type `B<T>`, so I can't understand why I am not able to pass object of type `B<T>`?

But `items[0].b` is not of type `B<T>`, it's of type `B<out T>`.

If you convert the second param of `doSomething` to `B<out T>` it will compile